# Horizontal center the content of a div with display: table-row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble centering the contents of a div with `display: table-row`.

Here's a [Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/zGLQX/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="table-row">
    <div class="left-right-padding">
        <ul>
            <li>TEXT EXEMPLE 1:</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="left-right-padding">
        <ul>
            <li>TEXT EXEMPLE 2:</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="left-right-padding">
        <ul>
            <li>TEXT EXEMPLE 3:</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    zoom: 1;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
 article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.clear {
    clear: both
}
.table-row {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: table-row;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.left-right-padding {
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
```

How can I center horizontally the content of a `div .table-row`?

I've tried using `margin: 0 auto` with `width: 100%`, but it did not work. Neither did using `text-align: center`.

Comment: I'm a little confused at what you are trying to do. There are three columns whose text is center-aligned in your fiddler link. What do you want to happen here?

Comment: Per KJ, it appears to be correct. Here is your same [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zGLQX/4/) with borders, so it is easier to see the centering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new div wrapper and put your display as `table` and `width: 100%`.

Put `text-align: center` in your table-row.

Answer (score 7):

From what I'm seeing, the `table-row` is being treated as an `inline-block` which leaves you with two options.

**Option a**
Wrap the `table-row` in a container div with `display: table` and `margin: 0 auto`

**Option b**
Have `table-row` use `display: table` and `margin: 0 auto`

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/zJ48q/1/

Answer (score 0):

Don’t have `table-row` elements hanging “in the air”, but put a table element around them – I used `inline-table` here so that the element can be centered by using `text-align:center` on the parent element (body):

http://jsfiddle.net/zGLQX/5/